# Run react native application on windows with npx react-native run-windows

Tags: typescript, windows, react-native, development-environment

I created a test app with react native via `npx react-native init Test --template react-native-template-typescript` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript). 
This seems to work fine, although it cant find the typescript template ([log as text](https://justpaste.it/2l2hw)
| [log as pictures](https://postimg.cc/gallery/dsdw3FS)). 
Now I cd into the created directory with `cd Test`, and run `npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite` according to the [docs](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started). This works fine, log [here](https://i.postimg.cc/pXr0745F/Screenshot-42.png). 
When I now run `npx react-native run-windows` as its being said in the documentation, I get the error message `Build failed with message Building Solution - error code 1. Check your build configuration` (log [here](https://justpaste.it/5tk9p) or [picture](https://i.postimg.cc/BvfXLjrB/Screenshot-46.png))

What I tried:

- running the rnw-dependencies.ps1 file a) from the pc and b) via `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force; iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-deps.ps1')` in an elevated power shell. This resulted in an big error message when I try to install the `Compilers, build tools, SKDs and Visual Studio`. The error message is pretty big, you can find the full log of the powershell [here](https://justpaste.it/6f4xl) or [pictures](https://postimg.cc/gallery/JXsH7BM). - **UPDATE**: installed every component by hand, now running `rnw-dependencies.ps1` causes no error anymore, everything is Ok; however the build error still persists
- installing the `MSVC v143 - VS 2022 C++-x64/x86-Buildtools (latest)` component with Visual Studio
- installing the `Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)`

What I am using:

- Windows 10
- nvm `v1.1.7`
- node `v14.18.1`, I stepped down because one on the internet suggested that, also available are `v17.5.0` and `v12.18.3`, both dont work
- Visual Studio Community 2022 - 17.1.0 (installed components and workloads picture [here](https://i.postimg.cc/bNR6FnTs/Screenshot-44.png))
- npx `v6.14.15`
- react-native-cli `v2.0.1`
- yarn `v1.22.15`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by installing the Visual Studio 19 version. Apperently, the 2022 version doesnt work.